# geom_text in barplot to show frequency over bars using R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have this graph that I want to show the count over the bar, however my code shows the number 1 inside the bars..

What I have:
[image]

What I am trying to make:

[image]

```
# Library
library(ggplot2)

# 1. Read data (comma separated)
df = read.csv2(text = "Id;Date
1;2021-06-09
2;2021-06-08
3;2021-06-08
4;2021-06-09
5;2021-06-09")

# 2. Print table
df_date <- df[, "Date"]
df_date <- as.data.frame(table(df_date))
colnames(df_date)[which(names(df_date) == "df_date")] <- "Date" # Set column name to Date
df_date

# 3. Plot bar chart
ggplot(df_date, aes(x = Date, y = Freq)) + 
        geom_bar(stat = "identity") + 
          theme_classic() +
          ggtitle("Date") +
          xlab("Date") + 
          ylab("Frequency") +
          geom_text(stat= "count", aes(label = ..count.., y= ..prop..), vjust = -1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have already calculated the frequency use `geom_col`.

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df_date, aes(x = Date, y = Freq)) + 
  geom_col() + 
  theme_classic() +
  ggtitle("Date") +
  xlab("Date") + 
  ylab("Frequency") +
  geom_text(aes(label = Freq), vjust = -1)
```

---

If you use `df` you can use `geom_bar` as -

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = Date)) + 
  geom_bar() + 
  theme_classic() +
  ggtitle("Date") +
  xlab("Date") + 
  ylab("Frequency") + 
  geom_text(stat= "count",aes(label = ..count..), vjust = -1)
```

Comment: Your code works, however the number 3 go outside the image so I can only see half the number.

Comment: If you expand the plot (or click zoom in RStudio Preview window) you'll see the complete number. Moreover, that is controlled by `vjust` so adjusting it to `vjust = -0.5` should fix that in preview window as well.